Add a Person Account from Outlook/Gmail integration
We have Person Accounts set up in an org and want the email integration to create one of these instead of a Contact or Lead (which we don't use). After setting up the integration app we don't see the option to do this - we are only getting the below options (clicking on the Add to Salesforce button brings up the same 2 options as the +).

How can I change it to allow it to ONLY create a Person Account? What am I missing that it's not showing? Where do I control which options are available?
It should also not create duplicates, right? Yet it did so when we tried it twice with the same email person/address. I assumed it would check first and notify or pick up the person is already there instead of adding a duplicate?
This article suggests that it should show the Person Account option if it's enabled, but it is not doing so for us.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383891&type=1

We found the answer with some help from Salesforce support:

Go to Setup -> User Interface -> Global Actions -> Global Actions
Click on New Action and populate 
Once created, open the action and click on Edit Layout 
Select which fields to make available - we kept only Account Name, Phone and Email. Save
Go to Setup -> Email -> Outlook Integration and Sync (or Gmail Integration and Sync).
Click on the arrow to open the Outlook Integration section and scroll down to Email Application Publisher Layouts. Click the New button.
Enter a name for the new layout and click Save
Edit the layout and remove the default buttons (like New Lead and New Contact) and leave only the new QuickAction created above (Create Person Account in our case) and save
Now click on the Publisher Layout Assignment button. Click Edit Assignment on the opened page and select the profiles and layout and click Save.
Add the Google Extension or Outlook Addin for Salesforce for your Gmail or Outlook and the new option should be available.

What a process...!
